# Philosophy of Synergy and Collaboration

Tags: reference-request, sociology, social-epistemology

So I'm trying to study sociology and the science of human collaboration. Are there particularly throrogh books on this topic that anyone knows of? And indeed I am looking mainly at the philosophy behind the behavior of groups, if that clarifies things a bit more.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about social science.

Comment: The book in my answer philosophises about ethics and society, demonstrating that the question can be treated philosophically and can be considered as not off-topic.  Similarly, questions on mathematical axioms are not considered off-topic in this forum.  Philosophy or metaphysics generally explores the area beyond (meta-) the ordinary area of fields like mathematics, art, etc.

Comment: @ChristopherE it definitely *looks* of topic. Perhaps Jking could verify that they are looking philosophically leaning social science books.

Comment: Thanks Chris D. (*not* for the Derrida suggestion, of course :P ), I think this question is no less on topic than most of the other reference requests. References to topics in the growing field of formal social epistemology might be relevant here, for example. I'll vote for reopening it. See where it goes.

Comment: Given the amendments, I vote to reopen. There's Hegel, John Searle, and collective action in applied ethics at a minimum that are applicable.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend Jacques Derrida's short book On Cosmopolitanism and Forgiveness.

http://www.amazon.co.uk/On-Cosmopolitanism-Forgiveness-Thinking-Action/dp/0415227127

Untypically, Derrida has written this book in a completely clear style.

> One of the world's most famous philosophers, Jacques Derrida, explores
>   difficult questions in this important and engaging book. Is it still
>   possible to uphold international hospitality and justice in the face
>   of increasing nationalism and civil strife in so many countries?

A review :

> "powerful and provocative...important, urgent, and demanding in... the
>   best sense....These essays masterfully articulate the impossibilities
>   of forgiveness and hospitality, but their real achievement lies in
>   understanding this impossibility as inseparable from political and
>   pragmatic exigencies." - Modern Language Notes